# Add certificate to chrome options in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

We have a requirement to trigger chrome driver from remote server. The URL that we are trying to reach from chrome driver accepts login only via certificates

Since the remote server don't have any certificates installed in it, process the login in blocked from remote server.

Is there any way to launch chrome driver using **selenium with certificate path given as an arguments** to chrome options while launching the driver?

Regards,
Naveen

Comment: Did you try with ignoring certificate in your code ?

Comment: You can use this links for more information                                                                                       https://www.guru99.com/ssl-certificate-error-handling-selenium.html  ,                            https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH240507.html          ,                        https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/7391219?hl=en

Comment: As i mentioned, I need to give path of my certificate which i will get it via service to chrome capability

Answer (score 0):

For a chrome driver you can add the SSL certificate.Try below code.

```
DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       

handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLErr);
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks  for your response. In my case, we will get the certificate from the service which i have to add to chrome capability. Suggested use case will work only if certificate is available in the system